# SPF setup for subdomain on different server

Tags: php, gmail, spf

I'm trying to set up an SPF record for a site that uses a domain and subdomain. The subdomain is hosted on a different server.

so http://www.mywebsite.com has the following SPF record.
v=spf1 ip4:10.10.10.10/18 ?all

but http://app.mywebsite.com is on a separate server and is sending PHP mail via info@mywebsite.com.

In Gmail I get the little red question mark that says "Gmail can't verify that mywebsite.com sent this email".

I'm wondering if part of my problem is the SPF records set up?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SPF is not related to web-domains, but only to mail-domains. So if you only send mails from the mywebsite.com domain, the SPF record needs to be created under that domain and not the www sub-domain.

The IP address in the SPF record should point to the mail-server, that will be sending the mails, and not the web-server where the PHP is running (In case the web-server and mail-server is on different computers)

Comment: If the mail server is Google Aps, what should the SPF record look like?

Comment: For Google Apps/G Suite the SPF Record should look like this `v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all` according to this article: https://support.google.com/a/answer/178723?hl=en